# Android how to know status of screen lock from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing custom UI for incoming call. I am almost done with this but now I want to load my custom UI activity only if screen is ON and user has a incoming call. I am doing all these stuff at BroadcastReceiver (android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE). So is it possible to get status of screen ON/OFF from the BrodcastReceiver.

I tried to follow the example http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/ but registering receiver from BroadcastReceiver is giving compile time error.

Please suggest me.

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


          IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
          filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
          BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new MyScreenReceiver();
          registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); //this gives error "The method registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter) is undefined for the type MyPhoneReceiver"


     }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could we get the error message that it's giving you? It's hard to know exactly what's happening without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

registerReceiver() is a method of Context, so you should call `context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);`

But you could do the following:

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if(pm.isScreenOn())
        {
            // load your UI
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: Boure thanks man, this is something I was looking for... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your question..

```
public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        wasScreenOn = false;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: intent.getAction() returns the "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" so it never goes into if..else. I edited my question with how receiver has been set over manifest file.